# how to use converted tex from mathtype equation in texmaker? Als

Tags: equations, texmaker

I have got the following TeX equation:

```
 \[r(t)=\frac{l}{1+e\cos \theta (t)}\]
```

Now I could not use this in Texmaker. To show the same equation Texmaker wants

```
$ r(t )= \dfrac{l}{ 1+e cos \theta (t)} $\\
```

So what should I do?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem: the first equation should compile fine. You should remove the `\\` in the second equation, and use `\cos` also here. Could you please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, including your preamble (`\dfrac` is defined in the `amsmath` package).

Answer (score 1):

The following compiles perfectly in Texmaker:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[r(t)=\frac{l}{1+e\cos \theta (t)}\]
\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image]